# Django rest easy way to decrease field value

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am using Django Rest and I need to decrease the value of an integer field by a certain quantity.

Right now I am first getting the value currently stored, then calculating the new value, and finally writing the new value back.

Is there any way to do this in a simpler way?

Answer (score 1):

Tried to decide between commenting and writing long form.  I think you are doing this best, if you are saying doing that server side vice like doing the calculation in javascript and then patching/ putting to update the model.

I'd probably do something like:

urls.py

```
...
url(r'^/descriptor/?p<model_link_pk>[\w\-]/subtract', viewsets.Subtractor.as_view(), name="subtract_thing_from_model"), 
...
```

Then in the viewsets:

```
class Subtractor(APIView):
     def post(self, request, format=None, model_link_pk=None):
         model_link = ModelObject.objects.get(pk=model_link_pk)
         model_link.integer_value -= request.data("subtract_by")
         model_link.save()
         return JsonResponse({"..."}) #or serializer
```

Let me know if this makes sense, or if a better way exists.